# Time out issue when users are working on weblogic application in peak business time

Tags: weblogic9.x

Especially during month ends users are facing time out issue in weblogic application. How to find out what causing the issue, where we can check the logs and all? We are using weblogic 9.2

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic 9.2 is a very old and outdated version. My first recommendation is to upgrade your weblogic to 12C
You need to take full thread dumps of your weblogic JVM. These thread dumps will help to identify the bottlenecks in your application